# Flutter buttons in drawer give error when tapped instead of navigating to the proper page

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to have some buttons in a drawer that the user can top on and be taken to another page/widget. However, it gives me an error and doesn't work. I'm not really sure what the issue is considering I'm doing this in another project and it works, additionally I checked the cookbook on Flutter's docs for how to do navigation and it also looks fine based on that.

Here is my drawer code which is inside a `Scaffold` widget:

```
Drawer(
    child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
            AppBar(
                automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                title: Text('Looped In'),
            ),
            ListTile(
                leading: Icon(Icons.info),
                title: Text('About'),
                onTap: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/about');
                },
            ),
        ],
    ),
),
```

Here is the error traceback that I'm getting

```
flutter: The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
flutter: Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.
flutter: The context used to push or pop routes from the Navigator must be that of a widget that is a
flutter: descendant of a Navigator widget.
flutter:
flutter: When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
flutter: #0      Navigator.of.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:1273:9)
flutter: #1      Navigator.of (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:1280:6)
flutter: #2      MyAppState.build.<anonymous closure> (file:///Users/garrettlove/Documents/learn/Flutter/loopt_in/lib/main.dart:59:29)
flutter: #3      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:507:14)
flutter: #4      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:562:30)
flutter: #5      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:102:24)
flutter: #6      TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:242:9)
flutter: #7      TapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:204:7)
flutter: #8      GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:156:27)
flutter: #9      _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:147:20)
flutter: #10     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:121:22)
flutter: #11     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:101:7)
flutter: #12     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:64:7)
flutter: #13     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:48:7)
flutter: #14     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:153:13)
flutter: #15     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:107:5)
flutter:
flutter: Handler: onTap
flutter: Recognizer:
flutter:   TapGestureRecognizer#2d408(debugOwner: GestureDetector, state: ready, won arena, finalPosition:
flutter:   Offset(98.5, 222.5), sent tap down)
```

**EDIT**
Here is everything I have:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import './pages/home.dart';
import './pages/categories.dart';
import './pages/about.dart';
import './pages/contact.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MyAppState();
  }
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int _selectedTab = 0;
  final _pageOptions = [
    HomePage(),
    CatPage(),
  ];

  Widget _buildDrawer(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          AppBar(
            automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
            backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(135, 142, 136, 1.0),
            title: Text('Looped In'),
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.info, color: Color.fromRGBO(247, 203, 21, 1.0),),
            title: Text('About'),
            onTap: () {
              //Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/about');
              Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AboutPage()));
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        accentColor: Color.fromRGBO(245, 93, 62, 1.0),
        primaryTextTheme: TextTheme(
          title: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
      ),
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        '/home': (BuildContext context) => HomePage(),
        '/about': (BuildContext context) => AboutPage(),
        '/contact': (BuildContext context) => ContactPage(),
      },
      home: Scaffold(
        drawer: _buildDrawer(context),
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Looped In'),
          backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(
            135,
            142,
            136,
            1.0,
          ),
        ),
        body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
          child: _pageOptions[_selectedTab],
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          currentIndex: _selectedTab,
          onTap: (int index) {
            setState(() {
              _selectedTab = index;
            });
          },
          fixedColor: Color.fromRGBO(118, 190, 208, 1.0),
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home),
              title: Text('Everything'),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.category),
              title: Text('Categories'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that `context` that you are using for `Navigator` has a parent `MaterialApp` or this error will occur. Wrapping your `Scaffold` widget with `MaterialApp` should solve the issue.

Also in your `MaterialApp` make sure to provide the `route` parameter with the route `'/about'`

It should look something like this:

```
    MaterialApp(
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        '/about': (BuildContext context) => AboutPage()
      },
      home: Scaffold(),
    );
```

**EDIT:**

Below you can find the solution based on your code. It works I tested. All you have to do is wrap your `Scaffold` with `Builder` like shown below:

```
home: Builder(
        builder:  (context) => Scaffold(
          drawer: _buildDrawer(context),
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Looped In'),
            backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(
              135,
              142,
              136,
              1.0,
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: I have it in a `MaterialApp` widget, and I tried adding in the extra stuff you have, still gives same error.

Comment: I've edited the answer with the solution based on the code you posted now. It should work. Please try

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a string in "about" Screen before Widget build

```
static const String routeName = "/about";
```

or just use this

```
onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => new AboutScreen()));
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GetMaterial App From Getx And Using Get Routes. Then specify all routes in get routes, otherwise this error will occure is console (Null check used in non null operator) and screen navigation will not work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).